# Jenkins pipeline with maven, The specified global settings file does not exist

Tags: file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, config

I have a jenkins pipeline job, that is depending on simple Jenkinsfile instructions:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Install Dep') {
            steps {
                  sh 'ls'
          configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: '3fada107-8341-40ec-b1b6-d49e48479157', variable: 'SETTINGS')]) {
          sh 'ls'
          sh 'mvn -gs SETTINGS install'
        }
      }
        }
    }
}
```

When i'm trying to build, i got the following Error:

```
+ mvn -gs SETTINGS install
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] The specified global settings file does not exist: /home/jenkins/workspace/FBPMCB2/SETTINGS
```

I'm using Config File Management plugin to define the settings.xml file, and it's defined but i'm not sure why i'm still getting this error, advise please?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the two options confused. From:
 [Maven CLI Options Reference.](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.0/maven-embedder/cli.html)

`-gs,--global-settings <arg>` Alternate path for the global settings file

`-s,--settings <arg>` Alternate path for the user settings file

From [Using the configuration files in Jenkins Pipelines](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin#ConfigFileProviderPlugin-UsingtheconfigurationfilesinJenkinsPipelines), it should be:

`sh 'mvn -s SETTINGS install'`

[Alternatively](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-maven/):

```
withMaven(globalMavenSettingsConfig: 'globalSettings', mavenSettingsConfig: 'settings') 

    sh "mvn install"
}
```

where `globalSettings` and `settings` are the names of your respective global and settings overrides (you can override the file-id with a readable name in the config file provider plugin)